# Is it possible to connect a SceneView to a GameScene without storyboard? [iOS SWIFT]

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, ios8

I have two scenes. The first (PresentScene) is connected to the PresentSceneView but the second scene (GameScene) is not connected to the GameSceneView.

PresentSceneView is created on the storyboard but not the GameSceneView and I don't want create it.

Is it possible to connect the GameScene to the GameSceneView without create it on the StoryBoard?

Here my GameSceneView code(doesn't work)

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import AVFoundation


var backgroundMusicPlayer:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

class GameViewController: UIViewController {


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}



override func viewWillLayoutSubviews()
{



    var skView:SKView = self.view as SKView
    skView.showsFPS = true
    skView.showsNodeCount = true
    skView.showsPhysics = true



    var scene:SKScene = GameScene.sceneWithSize(skView.bounds.size)
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill
    skView.presentScene(scene)

    var bgMusicURL:NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("fond", withExtension: "mp3")!
    backgroundMusicPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: bgMusicURL, error:nil)
    backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
    backgroundMusicPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    backgroundMusicPlayer.play()


}

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.AllButUpsideDown.toRaw())
    } else {
        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All.toRaw())
    }
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

}

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

```
let gameScene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
        gameScene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
        skView.presentScene(gameScene)


instead of 


  var scene:SKScene = GameScene.sceneWithSize(skView.bounds.size)
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill
    skView.presentScene(scene)
```